# How can i delete all vectors in a namespace of an index in pine cone

Tags: javascript, error-handling, namespaces

I am facing a challenge when it comes to deleting vectors in a namespace in pinecone. I am using javascript and trying to delete all vectors in a namespace,I get this error “[ErrorWithoutStackTrace: No ids provided]”, could anyone be knowing why this is and how to solve it? thanks in advance

I have tried using this code, “await index.delete1([ ], true, “example-namespace”);” as specified in the Delete vectors by namespace part of the pinecone documentation but i get the error mentioned above,

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution:

```js
await index.delete1({
  deleteAll: true,
  namespace,
});
```

I got this from the Pinecone GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const index = pinecone.Index("your_index_name");
await index.delete1({
  deleteAll: true,
  namespace: "your_namespace_name"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a node.js script I wrote to delete all vectors in all namespaces:

```
(async () => {
    // Import the PineconeClient
    const { PineconeClient } = require('@pinecone-database/pinecone');
    const axios = require('axios'); // Ensure axios is imported

    // Declare your API key and environment
    const PINECONE_API_KEY = process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY;
    const PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT = 'asia-northeast-gcp'; // replace with your environment

    // Create the client
    const client = new PineconeClient();

    // Initialize the client
    await client.init({
        apiKey: PINECONE_API_KEY,
        environment: PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT,
    });

    // select my index
    const index = client.Index('atheneum');

    // get all of the namespaces using curl equivalent and parsing the response

    let namespacesArr = [];
    try {
        // Make a GET request
        const url = `${process.env.PINECONE_API_ENDPOINT}/describe_index_stats`;
        const response = await axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                'Api-Key': PINECONE_API_KEY,
            },
        });

        // Parse the response
        namespacesArr = Object.keys(response.data.namespaces);
        console.log(namespaces);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('error describing index', error);
    }

    // iterate through namespaces and delete all indexes
    for (const namespace of namespacesArr) {
        try {
            await index.delete1({
                deleteAll: true,
                namespace,
            });
            console.log(`Deleted all vectors in namespace: ${namespace}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(
                `Error deleting vectors in namespace: ${namespace}`,
                error
            );
        }
    }
})();
```

If you want to delete just one namespace, you can modify it like so:

```
    let namespacesArr = ["your namespace that you want to delete"];

    // iterate through namespaces and delete all indexes
    for (const namespace of namespacesArr) {
        try {
            await index.delete1({
                deleteAll: true,
                namespace,
            });
            console.log(`Deleted all vectors in namespace: ${namespace}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(
                `Error deleting vectors in namespace: ${namespace}`,
                error
            );
        }
    }
```

You would have to install axios and the pinecone client libs:

```
npm install --save-dev axios
npm install --save-dev @pinecone-database/pinecone
```

And then you can run the script like this:

```
node ./path/to/script/node-delete-all-indexes.js
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const deleteAllVectorsOfIndex = async () => {

        const index = pinecone.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX_NAME);
        const deleteResponse = await index.delete1({
            deleteAll: true,
            namespace: process.env.PINECONE_NAME_SPACE
        })
        console.log("deleteResponse: ", deleteResponse);

    }
    deleteAllVectorsOfIndex();
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade of pinecone library to version 1 it should be coded as follows:

```
  const pineconeClient = new Pinecone({
    apiKey: PINECONE_API_KEY,
    environment: PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT
  })
  const index = pineconeClient.Index(indexName)
  const namespaceIndex = index.namespace(nameSpace);
  const res = await namespaceIndex.deleteAll();
```